# Changing UI according to text size in wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox, listitem

```
<ListBox Margin="0,2,0,0"   SelectionChanged="OnSelectionChanged" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" x:Name="lstUcpPanel" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource myContainerStyle}">


            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <toolkit:WrapPanel Width="Auto" Height="Auto"  Margin="-7,-8,-7,0"  ItemWidth="246" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>


            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border  BorderThickness="1"  Margin="3.5,1,0,0"   BorderBrush="Transparent">
                        <StackPanel  Orientation="Vertical"  Background="LightGray">
                            <Image Height="115" Width="115" Margin="2" Source="{Binding categoryImageName}" ></Image>
                            <TextBlock  Text="{Binding name}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>

                    </Border>

                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

I am using the above code for showing a data as in following format:

[image: its the correct format]

but when the [name] is long like "Settings flkjadsflka fdsaflksdj flhasdjhfl asd", then the design becomes like this:

[image: this is distorted format]

What i want to know is that is there anyway i can show the items in a uniform format without any distortion with uniform height of the item.

Answer (score 1):

Set the stretch property on your image to Stretch="Fill"

```
<Image Height="115" Width="115" Margin="2" Source="{Binding categoryImageName}" Stretch="Fill" ></Image>
```

Comment: sorry it didnot worked. The problem here is not with the image. the problem is with the itemheight. I want uniformity in each item height

Answer (score 1):

How about giving the items in the WrapPanel a fixed Height?

```
<toolkit:WrapPanel ItemHeight="80" ... />
```

Comment: i have tried that but this will not show the complete text in the item.

Comment: What is the Height you specified?

Comment: <toolkit:WrapPanel ItemHeight="168"  />

Comment: i want to set the height of the items dynamically